# R dataframe - extract pair of rows based on two variables then combine the rows based on custom colwise function

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Trying to consolidate sample pairs and their variables based on whether the sample pair has a TRUE or FALSE boolean in one or both of its sample type. some samples may have only one sample type, but never more than 1 A and 1 B type samples.

for the dataframe below:

```
   a     b     c      d      e     f      g     h      samples_name sample_type
1  FALSE FALSE FALSE  FALSE  FALSE TRUE   FALSE FALSE  PAEEYP         A
2  FALSE TRUE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE FALSE  FALSE FALSE  PAEEYP         B
3  FALSE FALSE FALSE  FALSE  FALSE FALSE  FALSE TRUE   PAERAH         A
4  FALSE FALSE FALSE  FALSE  FALSE FALSE  FALSE TRUE   PAERAH         B
5  FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE   TRUE  FALSE  FALSE FALSE  PAKIYW         A  \\only has A sample
```

4 possible values 1) FALSE = both FALSE; 2)A = TRUE in A only; 3)B = TRUE in B only, 4)TRUE = both TRUE

```
   a     b     c      d      e     f      g     h      samples_name
1  FALSE B     FALSE  FALSE  FALSE A      FALSE FALSE  PAEEYP         
2  FALSE FALSE FALSE  FALSE  FALSE FALSE  FALSE TRUE   PAERAH         
3  FALSE FALSE FALSE  A      A     FALSE  FALSE FALSE  PAKIYW
```

I am stuck and don't know how to do it. I suppose I need to subset/group them by samples name, sort them based on sample type, then apply some colwise ifelse function in each subset/group before merging into a dataframe. I thought about using ddply to do the subsetting and apply colwise function but I can't get my head around. Somehow I think I am overthinking the problem, any help will be appreciated .

Comment: One approach, which you touch on, is to split the data frame into lists, based on the `samples_name`, using something like `split(df, f = df$samples_name)`, then applying a function, using `lapply` which goes through each column and checks your conditions...

Comment: Maybe change the question title to "Conditional merging of logical vectors"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into some issues because your desired output mixes logical and character...

This solution is not the most pretty. It is hacked together on the fly ;-).
But perhaps it will set you in the right direction, or inspire others to come up with better answers...

**sample data**

```
library( data.table )

DT <- fread("a     b     c      d      e     f      g     h      samples_name sample_type
  FALSE FALSE FALSE  FALSE  FALSE TRUE   FALSE FALSE  PAEEYP         A
  FALSE TRUE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE FALSE  FALSE FALSE  PAEEYP         B
  FALSE FALSE FALSE  FALSE  FALSE FALSE  FALSE TRUE   PAERAH         A
  FALSE FALSE FALSE  FALSE  FALSE FALSE  FALSE TRUE   PAERAH         B
  FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE   TRUE  FALSE  FALSE FALSE  PAKIYW         A")
```

**code**

```
#melt to long
DT.melt <- melt( DT, id.vars = c( "samples_name", "sample_type" ) )
#set TRUE/FALSE to 1/0
DT.melt[, value := as.numeric( value )]
#only keep roes where value > 0
ans <- DT.melt[ !value == 0, ]
ans <- ans[, .(total = paste0(sample_type, collapse = "")), by = .(samples_name, variable)]
ans[ total == "AB", total := "TRUE"]
#    samples_name variable total
# 1:       PAEEYP        b     B
# 2:       PAKIYW        d     A
# 3:       PAKIYW        e     A
# 4:       PAEEYP        f     A
# 5:       PAERAH        h  TRUE

#create new melt without the sample_type
DT.melt2 <- melt( DT, id.vars = c( "samples_name" ), measure.vars = patterns("^[a-h]$") )
#set value to character, drop duplicates
DT.melt2 <- unique( DT.melt2[, value := as.character(value)], by = c("samples_name", "variable"))
#update join answer
DT.melt2[ ans, value := i.total, on = .(samples_name, variable)]
#and cast back to wide format
dcast(DT.melt2, samples_name ~ variable, value.var = "value")
```

**output**

```
#    samples_name     a     b     c     d     e     f     g     h
# 1:       PAEEYP FALSE     B FALSE FALSE FALSE     A FALSE FALSE
# 2:       PAERAH FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
# 3:       PAKIYW FALSE FALSE FALSE     A     A FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution, this actually looks neat, and blew my mind once again how simple a solution can be. I am rather new to R and it is the first time I come across the := operator and the dcast function. the only thing I don't understand is how you join the ans with DT.melt2, can you explain further how`DT.melt2[ ans, value := i.total, on = .(samples_name, variable)]` actually works? I cannot comprehand having 3 commas inside [ ], is `on =` an option?

Comment: Just found this blog post which go in-depth about the data.table library and now I understand how a lot of things work with your example, the syntaxwith data.table is actually more straight forward compare to dplyr, and the performance is a lot better as well, I think I will use more of it from now on because I am dealing with quite large data (>300,000 rows). https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/05/data-table-data-frame-work-large-data-sets/